# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: when pip install --upgrade gensim

Tags: python, pip, gensim

I am trying to install gensim through because I am working on Topic Modelling with Python on Windows 10.
I did:

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

and I keep encountering error:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\swat_\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\swat_\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jq6jmo27\\gensim_b5ab7f463fbc44d1850e29dba11294b4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\swat_\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jq6jmo27\\gensim_b5ab7f463fbc44d1850e29dba11294b4\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\swat_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-090khyko\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\swat_\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\gensim'
     cwd: C:\Users\swat_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jq6jmo27\gensim_b5ab7f463fbc44d1850e29dba11294b4\
Complete output (382 lines):
```

then an output of 382 lines that all resemble:

> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim
> copying gensim\downloader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim
> copying gensim\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim
> copying gensim\matutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim
> copying gensim\nosy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim
> copying gensim\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim
> copying gensim_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim\corpora
> copying gensim\corpora\bleicorpus.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim\corpora
> copying gensim\corpora\csvcorpus.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim\corpora
> copying gensim\corpora\dictionary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim\corpora
> copying gensim\corpora\hashdictionary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gensim\corpora
> ....

then ends with this.

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\swat_\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\swat_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-42rc4g6q\gensim_9e111ba4f41b4925a9f3fc8cdd0170f7\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\swat_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-42rc4g6q\gensim_9e111ba4f41b4925a9f3fc8cdd0170f7\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\swat_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3djkmh1b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\swat_\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\gensim' Check the logs for full command output.

I have tried to update setuptools by:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Didn't help.. anybody know what to do?

Comment: Can you paste the full log? The current log doesn't include the actual error.

Comment: yes - i have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing missing Visual Code C++ 14 tools.